# Python tqdm quits before iterating when total is specified

Tags: python, tqdm

I've been looking for a progress bar solution and came across tqdm. After integrating it into my program and following the examples, it ran fine with the iterable that I specified, but initially did not display a progress bar. I found out that the iterable I was using did not support `len`. I modified the code so that the `total` parameter was manually specified, and now, running the loop causes the program to quit at 0% progress. Below are the initial and modified code with output:

Initial code:

```
import pathlib
from tqdm import tqdm

paths = pathlib.Path('F://Music').rglob('*.mp3')

for f in tqdm(paths):
    # do stuff that takes time
    print(f.name) # prints ok
```

Initial output: `320it [00:00, 25528.56it/s]`

Modified code:

```
import pathlib
from tqdm import tqdm

paths = pathlib.Path('F://Music').rglob('*.mp3')

cnt = 0
for p in paths: cnt += 1

for f in tqdm(paths, total=cnt):
    # do stuff that takes time
    print(f.name) # line not reached
```

New output: `0%|                                                                                | 0/320 [00:00<?, ?it/s]`

It seems like specifying the `total` in this case breaks it, even though the total count is correct.

Comment: The problem is that `paths` is a generator object.  When you iterate over it to find it's length you exhaust it and it's empty when you actually try to do stuff.  Try `paths = list(pathlib.Path('F://Music').rglob('*.mp3'))` and then you should be able to omit the explicit `total` as `tqdm` knows how to find the `total` for lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `paths` defined by `paths = pathlib.Path('F://Music').rglob('*.mp3')` is not a data structure like a list, but a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator).

When you iterated over it to get its length in the variable `cnt`, you exhausted the generator, and when you tried to get the data from it a second time (when you used `tqdm`), that data did not exist anymore.

One way to convert a generator into a list is to do an actual conversion, i.e
`paths_list = list(paths)`, and then call `tqdm` over it. It might not be the best solution if your `paths` variable contains an enormous amount of data though.

---

This code should work fine :

```
import pathlib
from tqdm import tqdm

paths = pathlib.Path('F://Music').rglob('*.mp3')
paths_list = list(paths)

for f in tqdm(paths_list):
    print(f.name)
```